# ¿Cómo pasar una variable String de una fecha a un objeto Date en JS y PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy sacando la fecha del servidor de PHP y quiero pasarla a un objeto Date en JS, este es mi codigo:

codigo js:

```
fetch("http://localhost:82/Con/reloj.php") 
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => reloj.value = data); 
         var fechaYHoraAc = reloj.value;
      var fechaYHora = new Date(fechaYHoraAc);
      console.log(fechaYHora);
```

Código de PHP:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
echo $s = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Al momento que se ejecuta el script del JS, en el archivo php imprime la hora exacta del servidor, después recibe el archivo js la respuesta del php, una vez haciendo esto en la variable fechaYHoraAc están los datos ya del servidor, me da como resultado 2021-09-17 12:40:00 (ejemplo), este dato lo quiero convertir a string y pasarlo a un objeto Date, con el siguiente codigo:

```
     var fechaYHora = new Date(fechaYHoraAc);
      console.log(fechaYHora);
```

Al momento de imprimir esa variable en la consola me da como resultado -Invalid Date, he intentado con Date.parse(fechaYHoraAc); pero no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?.

Comment: Recomiendo poner `console.log(data)` en el ultimo `then` ... porque poniendo esto en consola es correcto `console.log(new Date("2021-09-17 12:40:00"))` por lo tanto el error debe estar en el momento de capturar el valor de `data`

Comment: Gracias por comentar, ya establecí lo que comentas y me muestra 2021-09-17 12:40:00 en consola.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ya vi cual es el problema...  tu conversión de la fecha no está dentro del ultimo then, está afuera... y fetch es asincrono, lo que indica que se ejecuta primero lo de abajo (el intento de conversion de fecha) antes de que `reloj.value` tenga un valor... Puedes o ponerle un await al fetch (dependiendo de donde lo tengas definido) o tambien puedes hacer la conversion dentro del ultimo then... algo asi:

```
.then(data => {
   reloj.value = data; 
   var fechaYHoraAc = reloj.value;
   var fechaYHora = new Date(fechaYHoraAc);
   console.log(fechaYHora);
});
```

Asi te aseguras hacer la conversion solo cuando ya `reloj.value` tiene valor.

Comment: Entonces el problema es que se esta ejecutando el console.log antes que todo y por ese motivo no tiene valor...

Comment: Si, correcto, es lo que esta pasando.